# swift - Increase speed of objects over time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, delay

I'm looking for a way to increase the pace of my game the longer you play it, I would like to achieve this by increasing the frequency of obstacles generated either after a certain time i.e. every 30 seconds or preferably after 10 objects (trees), have been generated so the longer you play the harder it gets.

This is my current set up, I use `repeatActionForever` how could I change this to something like `repeatAction10Times` with a different delay variable for each loop?

```
//in didMoveToView

    treeTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "tree")
    treeTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    var distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 0.1);
    var moveTrees = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y:0, duration:NSTimeInterval(0.006 * distanceToMove));
    var removeTrees = SKAction.removeFromParent();
    moveAndRemoveTrees = SKAction.sequence([moveTrees, removeTrees]);

    var spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnTrees()})

//this delay is what I would like to alter for each loop

    var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.2))

    var spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
    var spawnThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelay)
    self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever)


func spawnTrees() {
    var tree = SKNode()
    tree.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + treeTexture1.size().width * 2, 0 );
    tree.zPosition = -10;

    var height = UInt32( self.frame.size.height / 1 )
    var height_max = UInt32( 220 )
    var height_min = UInt32( 100 )
    var y = arc4random_uniform(height_max - height_min + 1) + height_min;

    var tree1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: treeTexture1)
    tree1.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y))
    tree1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tree1.size)
    tree1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    tree1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = treeCategory;
    tree1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    tree1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    tree.addChild(tree1)



    tree.runAction(moveAndRemoveTrees)

    trees.addChild(tree)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the simple `action.speed` code.

For example: Instead of running the action `spawnThenDelay` ten times and then running some code and repeating, try making a counter. Create a global variable at the very top of the code called `counter`, or whatever you want to call it. In `spawnTrees()`, change the code to this:

```
func spawnTrees() {
    var tree = SKNode()
    tree.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + treeTexture1.size().width * 2, 0 );
    tree.zPosition = -10;
    counter++

    ... }
```

And then in the `update()`, check to see if counter is above 10.

```
if counter == 10 {
     self.actionForKey("spawnThenDelayForever").speed += 10.0 // Or some integer/float like that
     counter = 0
}
```

Now, what this will do is run the code inside that if-statement for every 10 times you spawn something. But to do this, you'll have to update your calling of `spawnAndThenDelayForever` to add a key to reference it with.

```
self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever, withKey "spawnThenDelayForever")
```

Let me know if there are any syntactical errors in what I gave you, or if it doesn't work quite right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this pretty much solves my question, just two questions..... What could I use to re-set the speed in my reset func?  Also, would it be possible to add a pause once the counter hits it's limit in affect giving the player a break of a few seconds before the next wave of obsticles are generated.

Comment: To reset the speed, I'm pretty sure it's just `self.actionForKey("spawnThenDelayForever").speed = 0.0`. As for pausing when the counter hits the number ten,  what do you mean by that? It would be added to that if-statement I gave you.

Comment: Thank you the reset works perfectly, with the pause I'd like the counter to reach ten then and before increasing the speed the spawning is delayed for 5 seconds, almost like entering the next level.  Also would it be possible to limit the speed as with the code you've given the speed could continue to increase making the game generate crazy amounts of nodes.  Thanks again!

Comment: For limiting the speed, just do another if-statement. `if speed <= 100.0 { self.actionForKey("spawnThenDelayForever").speed += 10.0 }`. For delaying the spawning, you'll have to do another if-statement inside the spawning function itself. `if counter < 10 { var spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay]) } else if counter == 10 { var spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0), spawn, delay]) }`. Hope that works out for ya.

Comment: Thank you, I cant quite get the 10 second delay to work properly, I end up with no change at all.  Would you be able to show how I need to re-write my spawning function?